# Getting error to run ionic app on android device

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3

This is my first ionic app.When I am try to run app on android then I am getting error.I searched many answer but nothing worked for me.

```
Error: Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/Users/arpansarkar/Library/Android/Sdk (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/arpansarkar/Library/Android/Sdk (DEPRECATED)
Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio,
or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please include gradle 
in your path, or install Android Studio
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.
```

I am export all require thing in my .bash_profile and I have android studio installed.
Please help me...Thanks..

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=$HOME/Library/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/emulator
export GRADLE_HOME=/Users/arpansarkar/Development/gradle-5.5.1/bin
```

this is my .bash_profile.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please provide what is the result of "ionic info" command?

This is my path settings by which I'm able to create an android build.

```
export GRADLE_HOME=/opt/gradle/gradle-5.4.1
export PATH=$PATH:$GRADLE_HOME/bin
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/prachishah/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```